# How do I use jQuery to retrieve "Result One" using the data-filters attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I use jQuery to retrieve "Result One A" and "Result One B" using the data-filters attribute? I want to retrieve every result that has "["FilterOne"]" as a data filter.

```
<ul class="list">
    <li data-filters="["FilterOne"]">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <span class="target">Result One A</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li data-filters="["FilterOne"]">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <span class="target">Result One B</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li data-filters="["FilterTwo"]">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <span class="target">Result Two A</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li data-filters="["FilterThree"]">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <span class="target">Result Three A</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: data-filters="["FilterOne"]" its wrong format! correct format double quotes inside single quotes or vice versa

Comment: Have you noticed that your `li` elements have 3 attributes each (`data-filters` with value `[`, `filterone` -- `filtertwo` and `filterthree` for the last two -- and `"]"` and not `li` elements with one single attribute `data-filters="["FilterOne"]"`? It seems to me you should have `<li data-filters="[FilterOne]">` instead. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working , but your HTML tag were somewhat not formatted( now with little bit modification)

```js
$(function() {

  var lis = $('li[data-filters="\\[\\"FilterOne\\"\\]"] > div > span.target').each(function(index) {
    alert($(this).text());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li data-filters='["FilterOne"]'>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <span class="target">Result One A</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li data-filters='["FilterOne"]'>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <span class="target">Result One B</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li data-filters="[" FilterTwo "]">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <span class="target">Result Two A</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li data-filters="[" FilterThree "]">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <span class="target">Result Three A</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```